# What if values in properties files are subject to change?

Tags: java, file, jar, io, properties-file

I have read that files within a jar file are not supposed to be modified, and I think that explains why getting an `outputStream` is not as simple as getting an `inputStream` calling `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` to read a file. When using properties files values are going to be retrieved during execution, but what if those values are subject to change? It would be tedious to recompile the program.

In my case those values are IP address, username and a path to an external file. So I guess I could not move the external file even by accident because my properties file in the jar have a different path to that file. Is this the way is supposed to be or is there a more flexible way that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually property files are located outside of jar somewhere on production system's classpath. Values are usually changed once in a while via provisioning scripts / manually and then only application restart is required, not a re-compile.

So, to sum it up, I'd suggest not having properties file inside the jar.